# Is there any wordpress plugin to enable a website to receive OTP based delivery confirmation like Amazon?

Tags: wordpress

I am setting up a E-commerce website using wordpress. I need to enable the platform to receive OTP/Pin based confirmation from customer at the time of delivering the order. Is there any wordpress plugin to achieve this in India or is there any other alternative o achieve this in wordpress E-commerce website.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are many SMS plugins are available for WordPress platform that is provided by bulk SMS service providers. These SMS plugins allow both automated and manual SMS sending features.

If you are looking for SMS plugin specially for the purpose of verification then you must go for OTP SMS sending plugin like SendOTP that can be enabled in your WordPress platform. SendOTP SMS plugin specially designed by renowned SMS service provider MSG91 for two-factor verification process through SMS services.

For enabling SendOTP in your WordPress plugin first you need to sign up on https://sendotp.msg91.com/ After signing up they will contact you back and then you can let them know your requirements according to which they will suggest you perfect Send OTP solution for your WordPress platform. They will provide you simple lines of code that you need to simply copy and paste on your platform.

After following this procedure SMS plugin will be integrated on your platform. Now whenever a user request generates this plugin automatically generate a 4 or 6 digits unique OTP code and send it to user’s provided mobile number in form of SMS then user enter the code on platform and verification process will be completed.